# Como fazer o inimigo virar ao player?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um jogo em que o inimigo segue o player para tentar o capturar. Porém ele segue o player de costas, com o rosto para traz, ou de lado. Há alguma maneira de que o inimigo siga o player virado para ele?

```
void Awake ()
{

    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player").transform;
    playerHealth = player.GetComponent <PlayerHealth> ();
    enemyHealth = GetComponent <EnemyHealth> ();
    Enemy = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Enemy");
    nav = GetComponent <NavMeshAgent> ();
}


void Update ()
{
    Enemy.transform.LookAt(player);

    if(enemyHealth.currentHealth > 0 && playerHealth.currentHealth > 0)
    {
        nav.SetDestination(player.position);
        transform.Rotate(player.position);
    }
    else
    {
        nav.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

}

[image: O inimigo (laranja) segue o player virado de costas]

Comment: `Enemy.transform.LookAt(player);` faz justamente isso. Só que o seu objeto `Enemy` precisa ter sido construído de forma que a frente esteja correta. Na Unity, a frente é [`Vector3.forward`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-forward.html), que o vetor `(0, 0, 1)` (ou seja, o eixo Z, da origem em direção à câmera). Vc precisa checar na ferramenta de modelagem que usou como ela está exportando os eixos do objeto.

Comment: Entendi, porém o LookAt não está funcionando de nenhuma maneira, do jeito que o modelo do inimigo inicia ele fica.

Comment: Você consegue fazer um [mcve] que reproduza o problema? Pode ser um outro projeto, com um cubo seguindo outro, se não desejar compartilhar algo do seu projeto mesmo. Aí eu posso tentar reproduzir aqui pra te dar alguma dica.

Comment: Cara, desculpa a demora para responder, mas eu finalmente resolvi o problema. O componente **"Animator"** que reproduz a animação do enemy correndo e tals, estava por algum motivo **bloqueando o eixo y**. O que eu fiz foi, criei um **Empty Game Object** e coloquei todos os scripts de movimento etc... e dentro dele coloquei o modelo do enemy com só o animator. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Ah, ok. O motivo era bem simples: se há um animator sendo executado com alterações numa propriedade qualquer (seja de rotação, translação ou escala), qualquer alteração externa será ignorada porque no próximo frame o animator alterará novamente aquele valor. Por isso o que vc fez funcionou (e, de fato, é o jeito correto quando a animação será independente do movimento externo). :)

Comment: P.S.: Eu votei pra fechar como "não ser reproduzível", porque existe a chance dessa pergunta ficar perdida. Mas, se vc mesmo criar uma resposta explicando o que aconteceu e o que vc fez pra solucionar, eu tiro o voto pra fechar e ainda te dou o +1 na resposta (dependendo da qualidade dela, claro).